# AWS Load Balancer Target Group failing Health Check

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, loadbalancer

I have fresh-installed `nginx` on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I created a Load Balancer with a Target Group that points to the EC2 instance. The health status of my target group on port 80 is **unhealthy**.

1. Does Health Status affect whether the Load Balancer sends the request to the instance?
2. I don't see any kind of request on the defined route for the health check. My security group allows http on the correct port.

I tried to recreate the instance, the load balancer allows all traffic from the security group.

Comment: How's your instance set up? Is it in a private or public subnet? Did you check in target group healtcheck why it failed? As for Load Balancer, if you have multiple instances and some of them are unhealthy, it will not send traffic to those that are unhealthy. On the other hand, if all instances are unhealthy, LB will act as if all instances are healthy and send traffic to them as defined by the algorithm (Round robin is default)

Comment: If the Health Check fails, then no requests will be sent to the target. Please show us the configuration of the Security Group on the EC2 instance. If the EC2 instance is in a public subnet, can you point your browser directly to the same URL being used for the Health Check? If so, what appears? Or is the instance in a private subnet?